# challenges "facing" or "faced"?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Among the annoying challenges facing the middle class is one that will probably go unmentioned in the next presidential campaign: What happens when the robots come for their jobs?

I can't understand why should use "facing" in "Among the annoying challenges facing the middle class".

Here are what I know:

- "that will probably go unmentioned in the next presidential campaign" is an attributive clause with antecedent "one".
- "What happens when the robots come for their jobs" is the appositive of "one".
- "Among the annoying challenges facing the middle class" is the subject of this sentence. It can be rewritten as "Among the annoying challenges which are faced by the middle class".

Comment: If you 'are faced by' something, it is 'facing' you. The writer just happened to choose one way of expressing it rather than the other.

Answer (score 0):

The present participle form "*facing*" indicates that this is a current state of affairs. In this case the challenges are **now** facing the middle class. The alternate form "*which are faced by*" also indicates a current state of things, but places less emphasis on the fact that it is a **current** state. It is also longer for no real change in meaning, which some would think a defect.  But basically the choice is a mater of style, the meaning is much the same. Each form is grammatically valid in this context.